# In jQuery SVG why do coordinates not work as expected

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I load two images in jQuery SVG using the code:

```
svg.image(0, 0, 330, 540, 'images/img1.jpg', {id: 'img'});
svg.image(0, 0, 330, 540, 'images/iPhone5png.png', {id: 'imgphone'});
```

After the images are loaded it looks like this:

[image]

I rotate the images (of bottles) to 90 degree:

[image]

Now if I try to more the (bottle) image left or right interactively using following code:

```
//Move Left
$('#moveleft').click(function(){
var svg = $('#svgphone').svg('get');
var cx = $('#img', svg.root()).attr('x');
cx = eval(cx) - 10;
$('#img', svg.root()).attr('x', cx);
});
//Move Right
$('#moveright').click(function(){
var svg = $('#svgphone').svg('get');
var cx = $('#img', svg.root()).attr('x');
cx = eval(cx) + 10;
$('#img', svg.root()).attr('x', cx);
});
```

It moves up or down instead of left (moved down) or right (moves up) as shown below:

[image]

Why and how to solve this problem?

TIA

Yogi Yang

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to use jsfiddle. I did try but I am not able to get it to work. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/9YN3y/